# Paramiko utf-8 workaround

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm trying to work around paramiko's strict utf-8 decoding functionality. I want to open the file in binary mode and read into a dataframe line by line. How can I do that?

```
remote_file = sftp.open(remoteName, "rb")
for line in remote_file:
    print(line.decode("utf8", "ignore"))
```

Comment: I would like to import the data as a dataframe, not just lines.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this is the original problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530700/error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa3-in-position-73-invalid-start-byte?noredirect=1#comment121114112_68530700

Comment: you can read all data from server and use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object using `data` - and then you can use it to create `DataFrame` - `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("header1,header2\n1,2\n3,4"))`

Comment: maybe if you opened in bytes-more  then you could use it directly in `DataFrame` `read_csv( remote_file , encoding='...')` because all problem with encoding could make `open()`

Comment: @furas I've tried to open it in 'rb' mode with all kinds of encoding but no luck :(

Comment: @furas UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 83: invalid start byte this is what gives me the 'rb' mode. The same as the 'r' mode.

Comment: @furas please find the complete error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530700/error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa3-in-position-73-invalid-start-byte?noredirect=1#comment121117482_68530700

Comment: did you try different encoding in `read_csv()` when you use `rb`? In previous question you tested only `text mode`. But different mode can make big difference. All problem can be in `open()` which later use `remote_file.read()` to send data to `pandas` - and `remote_file.read()` in text mode may convert it automatically with `utf8` but when you use `rb` then you have opportunity to set different encoding and it may work.

Comment: BTW: if you have remoter file in `latin1` then you should use `decode('latin1')`, not `decode('utf8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on my server and I see

This code

```
remote_file = sftp.open(remoteName)
print(remote_file.read())
```

reads data as `bytes` - even if I don't set `bytes-mode` (`rb`)

This code

```
remote_file = sftp.open(remoteName)
print(remote_file.readlines())
```

normally reads data as `string` but can read as `bytes` when I set `bytes-mode` (`rb`).

It seems when I use `read_csv(remote_file)` then it use some inner wrapper and it automatically converts with `utf-8` - even if I set `bytes-mode` (`rb`) - and settings `encoding` in `read_csv` can't change it.

But I can use `read()` with `io.StringIO` to convert it manually with ie. `latin1`

```
import io

remote_file = sftp.open(remoteName)

bytes = remote_file.read()
text = bytes.decode('latin1')
#text = remote_file.read().decode('latin1')

file_obj = io.StringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(file_obj)
#df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Besed on answer in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68536149/1832058) it works with `io.BytesIO` and `encoding` in `read_csv`.

```
import io 

remote_file = sftp.open(remoteName)

bytes = remote_file.read()

file_obj = io.BytesIO(bytes)

df = pd.read_csv(file_obj, encoding='latin1')
#df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(bytes), encoding='latin1')
```